# concat/forkJoin to ensure one observable completes before another

Tags: redux, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I want to subscribe to two different streams, A and B.

However, though both events might be buffered, all of A must complete before any async tasks with B are processed.

input stream

---A1----B1----B2----A2---->

desired output

------ResponseA1-------------ResponseA2-------ResponseB1----ResponseB2--->

I initially attempted

```
outputStream = Observable.concat(A,B)
```

I noticed that B would not fire. Is this a use case for forkJoin?

---

Edits:

- Stream A doesn't complete in the Rx sense since we want to stay subscribed to the same set of events (in this case redux actions)
- What I'm really trying to specify around Stream A is that its "completion" event looks to fulfill two conditions:

  1. Are all buffered async tasks from A complete?
  2. Is the buffer empty?

This is extremely imperative because I'm refactoring our codebase from sagas.

If I could say this in "Rx-speak"

```
StreamA = actionStream.concatMap(action => longAsyncTask())
StreamB = actionStream.switchMap(action => shortAsyncTask())

MasterStream = Observable.forkJoin(StreamA, StreamB)
```

I would expect MasterStream to have both streams subscribed to their requisite actionTypes, have StreamA tasks emit values first, and only emit a val from StreamB once StreamA is no longer emitting values

Comment: "all of A must complete before any async tasks with B are processed"

you said complete, but the input/output stream diagrams aren't clear if A truly complete's in the Rx sense? Also, are both A and B hot/multicast? i.e they are emitting events (that you need) whether or not you are subscribed

Comment: Answering specifically the hot/multicast question - if it is possible to have StreamB "react" to StreamA being empty/complete, I don't think multicasting is necessary.

Comment: Whether or not they are multicast majorly changes what I would do. It's also really important to truly mean "complete", the RxJS subscription calls complete(), there are no more values.

Comment: I think multicasting will be necessary. StreamA needs to emit values as results from tasks in its buffer AND emit an "empty" event for StreamB.